# How do I change the Cypress Output when tests have run in CMD

Tags: javascript, reporting, cypress

I am running Cypress tests in Jenkins. However, I need the default output to change. I would like a table structure with the test name and another column for the pass or fail status.

The default output is shown below:

```
  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:    3.1.5                                                                              │
  │ Browser:    Chrome 72                                                                          │
  │ Specs:      2 found (Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js, tsconfig.json)                       │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running: Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js...                                          (1 of 2) 



  1) Correct credentials login

  √ Incorrect credentials login (2082ms)

  1 passing (3m)
  1 failing

  1)  Correct credentials login:
     CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'button#btnSearch', but never found it.
      at Object.cypressErr (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:65377:11)
      at Object.throwErr (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:65342:18)
      at Object.throwErrByPath (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:65369:17)
      at retry (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:58910:16)
      at http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:51018:18
      at tryCatcher (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:127298:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:125316:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:125373:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:125418:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:125493:18)
      at Async._drainQueue (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122222:16)
      at Async._drainQueues (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122232:10)
      at Async.drainQueues (http://quicktest.aclessentials.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122106:14)




  (Results)

  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        2                                   │
  │ Passing:      1                                   │
  │ Failing:      1                                   │
  │ Pending:      0                                   │
  │ Skipped:      0                                   │
  │ Screenshots:  1                                   │
  │ Video:        false                               │
  │ Duration:     2 minutes, 52 seconds               │
  │ Spec Ran:     Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js │
  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


  (Screenshots)

  - C:\cypress\screenshots\Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js\Correct credentials login (failed).png (1920x969)


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running: tsconfig.json...                                                                (2 of 2) 


  0 passing (2ms)


  (Results)

  ┌─────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        0             │
  │ Passing:      0             │
  │ Failing:      0             │
  │ Pending:      0             │
  │ Skipped:      0             │
  │ Screenshots:  0             │
  │ Video:        false         │
  │ Duration:     0 seconds     │
  │ Spec Ran:     tsconfig.json │
  └─────────────────────────────┘


====================================================================================================

  (Run Finished)


      Spec                                                Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped 
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ × Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js       02:52        2        1        1        -        - │
  ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √ tsconfig.json                               6ms        -        -        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    1 of 2 failed (50%)                         02:52        2        1        1        -        -
```

I only want the bottom of the output to display:

```
(Run Finished)


      Spec                                                Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped 
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ × Login_With_User_Credentials.spec.js       02:52        2        1        1        -        - │
  ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √ tsconfig.json                               6ms        -        -        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    1 of 2 failed (50%)                         02:52        2        1        1        -        -
```

Is there a config file that has the format set out? If so where do I find this? 
I have also tried creating a custom report config file but have no luck with it thus far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the mocha reporter to `min` results in only the summary of each test and a total summary being printed.

`cypress.json`

```
{
  "reporter": "min"
}
```

For more custom output, you will have to build your own. Take a look at the [`base` reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/base.js) and the [`min` reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/min.js) in the mocha repository.

There are also a number of other reporters you could try out, [here](https://mochajs.org/#reporters).